# Was bedeutet „eines“ in Hölderlins „Wurzel alles Übels“?

Tags: poetry

> Wurzel alles Übels
>
> Einig zu sein, ist göttlich und gut; woher ist die Sucht denn
>   Unter den Menschen, daß nur Einer und Eines nur sei?

Was bedeutet dann *Eines* bzw. *eines* da? Ist es da im Sinne von *von jemandem*, also in Genitiv?

---

<sup>Alternative Rechtschreibung:</sup>

> <sup>Wurzel alles Übels</sup>
>
> <sup>Einig zu sein, ist göttlich und gut; woher ist die Sucht denn
>
>   Unter den Menschen, daß nur einer und eines nur sei?</sup>

Answer (score 4):

Grammatikalisch ist der (Teil-)Satz ziemlich klar: *Einer* und *Eines* sind beide Nominativ Singular, einmal im Maskulinum und einmal im Neutrum. *Nur Einer und nur Eines* stehen parallel, was allerdings durch die Wortstellung ([Chiasmus](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chiasmus)) etwas verschleiert wird, und bilden das Subjekt. *Sei* ist hier das Vollverb (‘existieren’).

Das lyrische Ich beklagt also den Wunsch vieler Menschen, es solle nur eine Person und nur eine Sache geben, nicht jeweils mehrere. Was das inhaltlich bedeutet, ist nun eine Frage der Interpretation.

Answer (score 1):

Für mich ist das ein *Nominativ*. Er sagt, dass *Einer* nur eine Rolle inne hat, also nur *Eines* ist.

Eine zweite Deutung, die ohne Kenntnis des Kontexts auch noch denkbar wäre: es gibt einen maskulinen Typen, *Einer* und ein sächliches Teil, *Eines*.

Answer (score 1):

Es wäre ein leichtes gewesen "Einzig zu sein ..." zu schreiben, wenn Hölderlin das gemeint hätte (Hubert Schölnasts Ansicht). Es geht nicht um die Einschätzung des Selbst sondern einer anderen Sache.

Man muss sich NICHT einigen, ob nun Schoko- oder Vanilleeis das beste ist, er verspottet die Sucht nach Einigkeit in der Bewertung. Sollen doch mehrere Vorlieben, Ziele und Meinungen nebeneinander bestehen.

Er preist keineswegs Gott und somit Einigkeit als göttlich sondern kritisiert gerade dieses Streben nach Einigkeit, die auch wenig mit der Gleichheit von Ralph M.R. zu tun hat. Eine Truppe braucht Einigkeit im Kampf, muss aber nicht Gleich sein um zu kämpfen. Hätte Hölderlin Gleichheit im Auge gehabt, hätte er es zu sagen gewusst.

*Einer* bezieht sich also auf eine abstrakte Person, *eines* auf eine allgemeine Sache.

Comment: Zum leichter Merken (Etymologie meines Nachnamens): An einem Ast hängen Schellen. Das ist ein Schellen-Ast. Meine Vorfahren stammen aus der Ost-Steiermark. Im lokalen Dialekt heißen die Schellen *Schöln*. Und so entstand mein Nachname: Schölnast (L vor N; Silbentrennung: Schöln-ast)

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: Sorry, meine Autokorrektur will immer Schön lesen. :) War keine Absicht, hab's korrigiert.

Answer (score 1):

Hölderlin kommt aus dem Umkreis des "deutschen Idealismus"/nachkantischen Idealismus. "Eines" und "Einer" bezieht sich hier auf den Monismus etwa seines Studiumsmitbewohners F.W.J. Schelling, namentlich auf seine Ich-Schrift und sein System des transzendentalen Idealismus, aber auch auf Schellings Lehrer Fichte und seine Wissenschaftlehre. Das Eine hat eine große philosophische Tradition, man spricht von der Henologie (vgl. auch https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Das_Eine ).

Edit: Er spricht also von dem Einen als "er" (der Eine) und von dem Einen als "es" (das Eine), aber es klar, dass der Eine das Eine ist. (Egal ob das Eine Gott wie bei Spinozas Pantheismus oder "das absolute Ich" nach Schelling ist)

Answer (score 0):

Hölderlin sagt hier aus, dass die Wurzel allen Übels darin besteht, dass die Menschen süchtig danach sind, einzigartig sein zu wollen, wo doch die Einzigartigkeit etwas Göttliches ist und dem Menschen gar nicht zusteht.

### Pleonasmus

Die Ausdrücke »*nur einer*« und »*eines nur*« sind ein Pleonasmus. Dasselbe wird mit anderen Worten ein zweites Mal gesagt, um eine Verstärkung zu erreichen. Beide Ausdrücke bedeuten hier *Einzigartigkeit*, und genau diese göttliche Einzigartigkeit, oder vielmehr das Streben der Menschen danach, ist die Wurzel alles Übels, und Hölderlin fragt sich (oder den Leser) woher dieses Streben kommt.

Im Gedicht zusammengefasst sind diese beiden inhaltsgleichen Fragen:

> Woher kommt die Sucht, dass nur Einer sei?
>   Woher kommt die Sucht, dass Eines nur sei?

In beiden Fällen ist gemeint:

> Woher kommt die Sucht, dass man einzigartig sei?

Hölderlin hat sich die literarische Freiheit genommen, das Wort »kommt« durch »ist« zu ersetzen, und er hat die Sucht näher beschrieben (die Sucht *unter den Menschen*).

Er hat auch die Partikel »denn« eingefügt, um seine Anteilnahme an der Frage zu unterstreichen, wobei er dafür einen ungewöhnlichen Platz gewählt hat (erwarten würde man diese Partikel zwischen »kommt« und »die Sucht«). Durch den ungewöhnlichen Platz (zwischen der Sucht und ihrer Beschreibung) bringt er seine eigene Anteilnahme stärker zum Ausdruck, und lenkt zusätzlich die Aufmerksamkeit des Lesers auf die Sucht, die ja die Wurzel allen Übels ist.

Und er hat, wie oben beschrieben, hintereinander zweimal dasselbe mit anderen, aber ähnlichen Worten gesagt um dem Gesagten mehr Ausdruck zu verleihen.

---

### Nachtrag zum Wort »Einig«

Das Gedicht beginnt mit dem Wort »*einig*«. Damit ist aber nicht »*gemeinsam*« oder »*vereint*« gemeint, sondern hier will Hölderlin das Wort offenbar in seiner ursprünglichen Bedeutung verstanden wissen.

Das sind die Ursprünge von »*einig*«:

- Neuhochdeutsch: einig
- Mittelhochdeutsch: einec, einic
- Althochdeutsch: einac
- Gotisch: ainaha, ainakls

Vom Gotischen bis zum Mittelhochdeutsch hatten die alten Versionen des Wortes »*einig*« ausschließlich die Bedeutungen

> *allein* bzw. *einzig*

Hölderlin verwendet das Wort hier also in dieser Bedeutung

> **einzigartig** = *eins-artig* = *eins-ig* = **einig**

Das Wort »*einzig*« geht auf dieselbe Wurzel wie »*einig*« zurück, hat sich aber im Mittelhochdeutschen davon abgespalten (mdh: »*einzeg*«). Dabei blieben die Wörter »*einzeg*« und »*einec/einic*« aber noch eine Zeit lang Synonyme. Die Bedeutungen der beiden Wörter trennten sich erst später.

Der Bedeutungswandel von »*einig*« zu »*vereint*« begann im 16. Jahrhundert. In denselben Zeitraum fällt die Verengung der Bedeutung von »*einzig*«.

Comment: Ist es irgendwie ein Wortspiel *einig sein*, *Einer sei* und *Eines sei*? Der erste Ausdruck scheint auch das Gegentil von den zwei letzteren zu sein.

Comment: @c.p.: Da deine Frage nicht in einem kurzen Kommentar beantwortet werden kann, habe ich sie als Nachtrag in meine Antwort eingefügt.